# How to find a tweet URL given the username and the timestamp?

Tags: twitter

I think the question is clear enough!

I want to get the URL of a tweet. I already know who tweeted it, and also the date and time of publishing that tweet.

Is there any way I can get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing for quite a while, I landed on this website called [topsy.com](http://topsy.com/).

Their servers store tweets since 2006, and the search has many useful filters.